# Communication between two portals:JSP

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, web

We have two java portals,say portal A and portal B

Portal A has some button called "communicate" .When we press it,portal A should contact portal B and portal B should then send a file to portal A as a reply.

The file is not a static file.The file should be generated according to the values that portal A has sent.ie every time when a request is fired a file is generated afresh and sent back to portal A.

Can anyone explain how to do this in java?..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can write some servlet in portal B. 
And call that servlet from portal A. You can send values to servlet.